# Rename the folder in IOS box v2 api

Tags: ios, file-io, box-api

The following the procedure given in box developer site .

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-d '{"name":"New Folder Name!"}' \
-X PUT
```

Here is my code :

```
NSString *newDirectoryName;
NSString *str;
NSString*fid = [[boxFilePathsArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"folderId"];
NSString * type = [[boxFilePathsArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"type"];
NSString * str_access_token = [[arrUseraccounts objectAtIndex:[DropboxDownloadFileViewControlller getSharedInstance].index] objectForKey:@"acces_token"];

if ([type isEqualToString:@"folder"])
{
    newDirectoryName =tempString;
    str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/%@?access_token=%@",fid,str_access_token];
}
else
{
    newDirectoryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",tempString];
    str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/files/%@?access_token=%@",fid,str_access_token];
}

ASIFormDataRequest *postParams = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
[postParams setPostValue:newDirectoryName forKey:@"name"];

[postParams setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
[postParams startAsynchronous];
postParams.delegate = self ;
postParams.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"RenameFolder" forKey:@"id"];
```

The response i'm getting is :

```
{
  "status" : 400,
  "help_url" : "http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors",
  "code" : "bad_request",
  "request_id" : "169126257953f1ed709ab32",
  "context_info" : {
    "errors" : [
      {
        "name" : "entity-body",
        "message" : "Invalid value 'name=dd'. Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name\/value pair",
        "reason" : "invalid_parameter"
      }
    ]
  },
  "message" : "Bad Request",
  "type" : "error"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.  I posted the JSON body. Here is my code.

```
NSString *newDirectoryName;
NSString *str;
NSString*fid = [[boxFilePathsArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"folderId"];
NSString * type = [[boxFilePathsArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"type"];
NSString * str_access_token = [[arrUseraccounts objectAtIndex:[DropboxDownloadFileViewControlller getSharedInstance].index] objectForKey:@"acces_token"];

if ([type isEqualToString:@"folder"])
{
    newDirectoryName =tempString;

    str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/%@?access_token=%@",fid,str_access_token];

}
else
{
    newDirectoryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",tempString];

    str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/files/%@?access_token=%@",fid,str_access_token];

}

NSDictionary *cid = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:newDirectoryName,@"name", nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:cid options:0 error:&error];
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:postData];

ASIFormDataRequest *postParams = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
//[postParams setPostValue:newDirectoryName forKey:@"name"];
[postParams setPostBody:data];
[postParams setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
[postParams startAsynchronous];
postParams.delegate = self ;
postParams.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"RenameFolder" forKey:@"id"];
```